# how to execute json-schema validator in java

Tags: jsonschema

i am new to json-schema i want to validate json data with json-schema,

this is my json data

```
{
users: [
    {
     "id": 1,
     "username": "davidwalsh",
         "phoneNumber": 987654321
        },
        { 
         "id": 2,
         "username": "russianprince",
         "phoneNumber": 9876541234
    }
      ]
}
```

this is my json-Schema

```
{
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "users" : {
            "type" : "array",
            "items" : {
                "type" : "object",
                "properties" : {
                    "id": { "type": "number" },
                    "username": { "type" : "string" },
                    "phoneNumber": {"type": "number" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now i dont no how to execute these files in program.
if any one have any examples please provide me some links.
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

JSON Schemas are not "executable" in themselves.  They are documents, that describe other documents.

To do something like validation, you need a validator that takes both the data and the schema as input.  The JSON Schema main site has a [list of software](http://json-schema.org/implementations.html) which might be helpful. :)